# New To SASS - Not Compiling

Tags: css, sass

Just decided to learn SASS, pretty easy stuff except a very basic file won't compile.

It's literally this basic:

```
$test: #ffffff;
```

Command:

```
sass test.sass
```

Error Message:

```
error: expected "
".
$test:#ffffff;
             ^
  test.sass 1:14  root stylesheet
```

I've no idea what it means by expected " - expected where??

Comment: it compiles well: [demo](https://www.sassmeister.com/gist/3436784988d451f13e15bc063ccc6bc7)

Comment: what version of sass are you using? Run `sass -v` from the terminal

Comment: sass -v
Could not find an option or flag "-v".

Answer (score 5, accepted):

please change extension `test.sass` to  `test.scss`. and you good to go. ***100% :)***

As per [sass-lang.com](http://sass-lang.com/documentation/file.SASS_REFERENCE.html#syntax).

> There are two syntaxes available for Sass. The first, known as **SCSS**
>   **(Sassy CSS)** and used throughout this reference, is an extension of the
>   syntax of CSS. This means that every valid CSS stylesheet is a valid
>   SCSS file with the same meaning. In addition, SCSS understands most
>   CSS hacks and vendor-specific syntax, such as IE's old filter syntax.
>   This syntax is enhanced with the Sass features described below. Files
>   using this syntax have the .scss extension.
>
> The second and older syntax, known **as the indented syntax (or**
>   **sometimes just "Sass")**, provides a more concise way of writing CSS. It
>   uses indentation rather than brackets to indicate nesting of
>   selectors, and newlines rather than semicolons to separate properties.
>   Some people find this to be easier to read and quicker to write than
>   SCSS. The indented syntax has all the same features, although some of
>   them have slightly different syntax; this is described in the indented
>   syntax reference. Files using this syntax have the .sass extension.